How to write an interceptor in nest
How to write an interceptor in nest, use documentation, carry out authentication. An interceptor is a class annotated with the @Injectable() decorator and implements the NestInterceptor interface.
Interceptors have a set of useful capabilities which are inspired by the Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) technique.

import {Injectable,  NestInterceptor,  ExecutionContext,  CallHandler,} from '@nestjs/common';import { Observable } from 'rxjs';import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

